# Using stateful helper classes in stateful stream operator functions in Flink

Tags: apache-flink

Can we have helper classes that reference Flink state used inside a Flink operator function.  The documentation examples all show the objects from the Flink state api referenced as fields directly by the opereator.  But I was wondering if fault tolerance is affected if I move the state into another class, for example:

```
///Operator function with reference to a stateful helper class
public class SomeStatefulFunction extends RichMapFunction<SomeInput, SomeOutput> {

    private SomeStatefulHelper helperInstance1;
    private SomeStatefulHelper helperInstance2;

    @Override
    public SomeOutput map(SomeInput someInput) throws Exception {
        return combineOutput(helperInstance1.helperMethod(someInput), helperInstance2.helperMethod(someInput));
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        super.open(parameters);

        this.helperInstance1 = createHelper("helperConfig1", "someMapState1");
        this.helperInstance2 = createHelper("helperConfig2", "someMapState2");

    }

    private SomeStatefulHelper createHelper(String helperConfig, String stateName) {
        MapStateDescriptor<Integer, Integer> descriptor =
                new MapStateDescriptor<>(stateName, Integer.class, Integer.class);
        MapState<Integer, Integer> mapState = getRuntimeContext().getMapState(descriptor);
        return new SomeStatefulHelper(helperConfig, mapState);
    }

    private SomeOutput combineOutput(SomeOutput output1, SomeOutput output2) {
        //Some way to combine output
    }
}

///Stateful helper class
public class SomeStatefulHelper {
    private MapState<Integer, Integer> state;
    private String helperConfig;

    public SomeStatefulHelper(String helperConfig, MapState<Integer, Integer> state) {
        this.state = state;
        this.helperConfig = helperConfig;
    }

    public SomeOutput helperMethod(SomeInput input) {
        //return something based on input, state, and helperConfig
    }
}
```

I have a job that uses this 'pattern' and it works in terms of processing, but I am not sure whether the state would be recovered in the event of failure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shouldn't affect the state recovery as it does not matter if the state is created in a separate class or directly in the `open` method. The operator still will invoke the same methods on state recovery. So, as long as You create the classes inside the `open` method You should be fine.